# How to access a function of an object that was returned as a pointer by another function.

Tags: c++, class, pointers

It's the guy who was making the boggle simulator again! This time I have the issue of having a function that was forced to return a pointer to an object for syntax reasons. I want to access a function of the object that said pointer points to. How should I go about this? My code for the functions involved is below.

```
boggleNode * nextNode(int adj){
    return adjacency[adj];              //For switching between nodes. 
}
bool getUsed(){
    return isUsed;
}
private:
boggleNode * adjacency[8];
char letter;
bool isUsed;
};
```

And finally, here is the function that contains the functions above:

```
int sift(boggleNode bog, string word, string matcher){
int endofnodes;
string matchee;
if (bog.getData() == 'q')
    matchee = matcher + bog.getData() + 'u';
else
    matchee = matcher + bog.getData();
if (compare(word, matcher) == 0){
    cout << word << endl;
    return 5;                                                 //If it finds the word, escape the loop. 
}
if (word.find(matcher) == 0){
bog.makeUsed();
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    if (bog.nextNode(j) != NULL){
        if ((bog.nextNode(j)).getUsed() == 0){
            endofnodes = sift(bog.nextNode(j), word, matchee);
            if (endofnodes == 5)
                return endofnodes;
            }
        }
    bog.reset();
    return 0;
    //If it doesn't find anything, move onto next adjacency. 
    /*any words share a common starting letter sequence with matcher*/
    //Sift using an adjacent node, and add the old string to the new one. 
    }
}
}
```

In which I am specifically asking about this line:

```
if ((bog.nextNode(j)).getUsed() == 0)
```

When I attempt to compile this code, I get " error: request for member
`getUsed' in`(&bog)->boggleNode::nextNode(j)', which is of non-class
type `boggleNode*' "

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want `if ((bog.nextNode(j))->getUsed() == 0)` [or `if (bog.nextNode(j)->getUsed() == 0)` if we remove superfluous parenthesis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `->` instead of `.`:

```
if ((bog.nextNode(j))->getUsed() == 0)
```

which is shorthand, in this case, for:

```
if ((*(bog.nextNode(j))).getUsed() == 0)
```